# Apply Filters Causing a 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: plugin-development, filters

I have a custom post type and need to display it in a certain way. I would like other posts to display as normal. When I tried to use the following code to accomplish this, I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

```
global $post;


//do this only for custom type
  if (!(get_post_type()=='customt'))
  {
    $rawContent = $post->post_content;
    $formattedContent = apply_filters('the_content',$rawContent);
    echo $formattedContent;
    return;
  }
```

I have googled around and found a lot of things regarding .htaccess but I don't think that is the case here. If I comment out the apply filters line (`$formattedContent =...`) and echo raw content, the post displays, but without formatting of course.

What am I doing wrong when I am trying to apply a filter?

Comment: Please show the function as a whole, not just the snippet.

Comment: I am certain that this is the path it's going down. If I echo something instead of apply filters(including just $post->the_content) it come out correctly.

Comment: I asked you to post the whole function. Could you please do so for later readers? It would also be good, so we can enhance our answers to a _real_ solution. Else it will be closed as _too localized_.

Comment: I think it probably should be closed..I had a variety of unrelated issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to replace your snippet with the following. The `global $post` isn't needed, when it's outside a function or method context and inside the loop, as then `$post` is already `global` and `get_post_type()`s default `false` arg with be replaced with `$post` inside the function.

```
if ( 'customt' !== get_post_type() )
    return print apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
```

Also make sure, that you're not calling it on some too early filter, like `plugins_loaded` or `init`, as the global `$post` object wouldn't be setup up.

Comment: This is the closest...I'm still having issues but I was calling with init which didn't help things.

Answer (score 0):

[**Post type name shouldn't contain capital letters.**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Also try pass `$post` object to `get_post_type()` function

**Like this:**

```
if(!get_post_type($post)=='customT'){
   //code
}
```

Comment: Sorry to lead you down the wrong path - the custom post type is lower case letters, I was just trying to make it more generic. I am confused about the second part of your answer as the code in the if block is running when appropriate, apply_filters is just not working right. Thanks for the quick attention

Comment: anything form php error log?